# Getting |as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

Im using crispy field on inputs for css speed.

I have my {{from.username|as_crispy_field}}.

When i submit the data i get a CrispyError at /client error.

Exception Type: CrispyError
Exception Value:
|as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field

What do i need to do to handle this in views ?

Comment: Is it possible that you've misspelled the `form` variable in the code you shared? You wrote `{{from.username|as_crispy_field}}`, when it should probably be `{{form.username|as_crispy_field}}`.

Answer (score 0):

it is supposed to be {{form.username|as_crispy_field}} instead of {{from.username|as_crispy_field}}.

PS. This is about 3 years old but I hope the answer will help someone at some point. Cheers!